# How to prevent enemy spawns in an artificial jungle biome?

Tags: terraria

An artificial Jungle biome can be created by planting enough jungle grass in one area and letting jungle vegetation grow.  Is there a safe way to do this without having enemies spawn?  For example if I want a jungle grass farm, will I be safe if I just provide background walls and enclose all the jungle grass, or will the artificial biome extend beyond the walls and allow jungle enemies to spawn outside?  How far would the artificial biome extend?

Note: This question is specifically about jungle but may apply to all biomes in general.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to prevent enemies from spawning in a Jungle biome (artificial or not), *build several houses and have NPCs move into them.* This is the only reasonable way to fully stop hostile mobs from spawning in general.

Note that during Blood Moons enemies will still spawn, even with NPCs nearby.

Comment: What if I want a farm that is not located near my NPC's?  I was planning an underground jungle farm, but gave up on the project because it looked like I would need a box several screens in size to contain a few jungle tiles that take up less than a screen.

Comment: "Mess with the bull, you get the horns." If you want an underground jungle farm, you get to deal with the hostile mobs there.

Comment: I'm not sure how that is relevant.  I want monsters ... *inside* the farm.  I'm asking where the boundary between inside and outside is so I know how big to make it.

Comment: aaaaah, i thought you were farming stuff like jungle spores and didn't want any hostile mobs. That makes more sense. The actual boundary would be about a screen and a half from where the music changes.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience in playing with Terraria, when you create an artificial biome, the game will treat it as if the biome "exists" to begin with.

The problem with walling your artificial biome is that, the jungle seeds will be unable to "grow". The artificial biome would grow the size you want it to be.

Here is a guide about gardening that could be relevant to you:

> http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Gardening

If you notice, the objects were grown according to how they are found in the wild, while creating an enclosure to make it easier on you to get the items.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Terraria Wiki, to keep enemies from spawning, or a least very rarely, move in lots of NPCS, and if you have the 1.13 or past put out Peace Candles along with a calming potion if you're near the biome, but remember, Calming Potions only work for a limited time, when Peace Candles only work when your in the range of it and it's placed on a table or crafting bench. Or yes you can but walls to stop spawning too. (I'm taking the text and saying it in my own word for the wiki.)

Comment: Probably because this is a 6 year old question, and your answer is almost entirely identical to the ones already given.

Comment: This would be a newer awnser be because this is new tips for 1.1.3 update and beyond

Comment: This does add new information, so I think it's a valid attempt at answering the question.  Whether it's right or wrong isn't something I would know, so I can't speak to that.  Beyond that...votes are a judgement of the post, not you.  Users can provide feedback, but are not obligated to.

Comment: Ok, is there anything else I should add?

Comment: Add references, expand on how peace candles stop monster spawning, mention that a calming potion only works temporarily, next to that although it is answered in an earlier question, a blood moon will still spawn enemies

Comment: Ok, got that, I just need a little bit of time.

Comment: How does this look, any better

Answer (score -1):

This is based solely on the fact that it worked once. I needed to be able to farm trees constantly so outside was dangerous. How I made it work is I built the bottom half of the area with stone and the top half with glass allowing sunlight in. The trick was the glass was several layers thick. Starting from ground level and working down. It is realistic but I only bothered to do it once. Over a year ago.

Comment: What does this have to do with preventing monsters from spawning in an artificial jungle biome?

Comment: Trees in terraria don't need sunlight. They only need snow blocks (boral wood), mud with jungle grass infection (mahogany wood), or dirt with grass infection (normal trees), as well as enough space to either side and above them to grow. So building a glass ceiling above a tree farm is irrelevant.